# Strange error while starting tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a custom tomcat which are used in our development stream, it work on PC of my colleagues, but on my PC it show strange error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 6/0/logs
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 6.0.logs
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: 6.0/logs.  Program will exit.
```

I try to google, but can't find anything similar. Any idea what such error can happend?

Comment: What is a *custom* Tomcat ?

Comment: and what are the configurations in catalina.sh

Comment: check your system jdk version.

Comment: That`s ok, I find out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there some interesting configuration. I just suppose that '6.0/logs' is part of the path in the configs. And I was right, I have path Tomcat 6.0/..., so I just rename a folder to another name without space (Tomcat_6.0) and error go out.